# Gdal_sieve not working with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm using the Sieve command within QGIS (Raster > Analysis > Sieve), but when I run the command with any variation of parameters, it completely changes the histogram of my raster data from between -0.140351 to 0.780933, to a binary output of 0 and 1.

[image: Before Sieve]

[image: After Sieve]

This example was run with a threshold of 2 and pixel connections of 4, on a NDVI image calculated from Landsat 7 imagery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand from the official documentation that gdal_sieve eliminates raster polygons if they are under a certain pixel size. It seems to work for image rasters but with a binary output.

I performed a 5 class cluster analysis classification in QGIS 2.4 Windows on the same NDVI image: 
Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Imagery  - Classification > Cluster analysis for grids
Then ran gdal_sieve on it for polygons less than 20 px:

gdal_sieve.bat -st 20 -of GTiff "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\LS7_20020326_lat52lon42_r24p204_toa_Cardiff_NDVI (1).tif" D:/Alexandra/HelpingPeople/Tests/LS7_20020326_lat52lon42_r24p204_toa_Cardiff_NDVI_sieve_clusters_20.tif

[image]
[image]
[image]